# How do I find "argument index out of range" from spdlog

Tags: spdlog

I'm occasionally seeing this in syslog:

```
[*** LOG ERROR #0027 ***] [2022-06-15 02:50:14] [MyApp] {argument index out of range}
```

But how do I figure out which line of code or function this is coming from? Does `LOG ERROR` mean it's coming from a call to `error()` or is it just indicating there's an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is triggering an internal spdlog exception, try registering a custom global error handler via [`spdlog::set_error_handler`](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/298a200f69d66114adde2d5d8ad34f2cce5a5b69/include/spdlog/details/registry.h#L66) and then setting a breakpoint in it, attaching your program from a debugger, stack walking to find the source of the problem.